# Google Street View and Google Maps

Tags: view, openstreetmap

Does the Google Street View app charge? We want to show the inside of the company 360 degrees. I am looking for detailed information about the Google street view application and its cost.

I am looking for detailed information about the Google street view application and its cost.But I couldn't find it.